# How to change the length of the space where tabs are displayed in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a `JFrame` that contains a `JTabbedPane` with about 16 tabs.

[image: 1]

However I would like to lessen the space where tabs are shown like so.

[image: 2]

How would I do this if I can?

Comment: *"However I would like to lessen the space where tabs are shown.."* .. ***Why?*** The 2nd variant seems less useful to the user.

Comment: You could wrap the tabs (tab layout policy) so several lines of tabs are displayed. One could also overlay the area of tabs with a single line JPanel containing `<` `>` buttons. I have seen examples in the net (years ago).

Comment: Probably you need to use `JideTabbedPane` which is provided by [JIDE Software](https://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm). This component allows to add a trailing component (in your case is an empty panel which takes some size).